# multiple sort criteria with different sort order equivalent is not available MongoDB .net SDK

Tags: .net, mongodb, sorting

I could not find equivalent .net code for "A".

Desc:
A:

> db.Some_Coll.find({"Feild1" : 123}).sort({"Some_Flag" :
> 1,"Some_Date":-1})

B:

> db.Some_Coll.find({"Feild1" : 123}).sort({"Some_Flag" :
> 1}).sort({"Some_Date":-1})

A != B

---

B===

> db.Some_Coll.find({"Feild1" : 123}).sort({"Some_Flag" :
> 1,"Some_Date":-1})

===

```
Some_CollObj.collection.Find(aggQuery)
     .SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending("Some_Flag"))
     .SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("Some_Date")).ToList();
```

A === ???
the below doesn't serve the purpose: as it does sort all keys as ascending

```
Some_CollObj.collection.Find(aggQuery)
 .SetSortOrder("Some_Flag","Some_Date") === 
  Some_CollObj.collection.Find(aggQuery)
 .SetSortOrder("Some_Flag","Some_Date").ToList();
```

Reference:
MongoCursor SetSortOrder(params string[] keys)
public virtual MongoCursor SetSortOrder(params string[] keys)
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver.Legacy/MongoCursor.cs

Comment: Are you stuck using the legacy driver for some reason?

Comment: I am using MongoDB.Driver.dll, v1.9.1.221.     
            And I saw the below in latest  git source 
 public virtual MongoCursor SetSortOrder(params string[] keys) ->  public virtual MongoCursor SetSortOrder(params string[] keys) -> 
            return SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending(keys));

Comment: Can you upgrade to the current 2.2.1 driver?

Comment: I'm asking because the docs for the current driver explain how to do this here: https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/csharp/query/#sort-query-results

Comment: I'll try the code..                     
thank you @John.